# how to visualize agent behavior in anylogic sample model?

Tags: anylogic, agent-based-modeling

I'm currently learning how to build evacuation model from this model:

https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/90677dc1-15c5-4bb9-917e-7f6547feceb7?mode=SETTINGS

However, I've been wondering. If I want to improve this model, how do I show the agent behavior? How do I visualize the statechart for this? Is it possible to create something like checkbox button to choose between the option of agents with panic behavior, one is not?

How do I do this? I'm not sure how can I connect the statechart with the Main.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions on *how to solve a problem*, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is a generic “how do I best do X” question. This is too broad for SOF and better asked in a forum like LinkedIn. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions here: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow . Welcome again, we are all happy to help on specifics :)

Comment: And check this article on how the AnyLogic community is used best: https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/11/12/an-introduction-to-the-anylogic-community